# C program store file to jagged array and sort it

Tags: c, sorting, jagged-arrays

I am trying to create C program to read a text file and sort it by ascending order. The example of text file is

```
2
3; 2, 5, 7
6; 4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 2
```

with the first line indicated the number of rows, the number after the ";" indicated elements each rows and elements separated by ",".
So my idea is to create a dynamic jagged array with rows as the first number, then point each row to the different array with element. Sort the pointer arrays first then sort elements of each arrays. This is what I have tried so far

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int SortLists();

int main ()
{
    int i,j = 0;
    char filename[10];          //name of the file

    char line[100];
    int rows = 3;               //I have to initialized this to test my code first
    int cols;

    int **jaggedArr;                            //jagged array
    jaggerArr = malloc (rows*sizeof(int*))  ;

    printf("Enter the file name with .txt : ");
    scanf("%s", filename);  

    FILE *filePtr = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    int num;

    if (filePtr != NULL) 
    {       
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePtr) != NULL) //read each line of the text
        {               
            cols = atoi(strtok(line, ";"));     //use strtk to break elements
            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    jaggedArr[i][j] = atoi(strtok(line, ","));  //parse into the jagged array                                   
                }
            }                           
        }       
    fclose(filePtr);    
    }
}


int SortLists(int list[], int size)     //sort method
{
    int i,j,temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if (list[i] > list[j])
            {
                temp =  list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a beginner in C, I am not familiar with the idea of pointer, which a lot different with C#. 
Sorry for my bad English as its not my first language. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: That repeated `strtok(line, ",")` isn't going to do what you want. The opener, delimited by `';'` looks promising, but the remainder of the line processing should be done with `strtok(NULL, ',')`. And maybe allocate some *memory* for those rows?

Comment: thank you for spend time answer my question. by allocate memory, did you mean to use the number of elements in the row to initialize the size of the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)

void SortLists(int list[], int size);

int main(void){
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX+1];
    char line[100];
    int rows, cols;

    printf("Enter the file name with .txt : ");
    scanf("%" S(FILENAME_MAX) "[^\n]%*c", filename);  
    FILE *filePtr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!filePtr)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    fscanf(filePtr, "%d ", &rows);
    int **jaggedArr;
    jaggedArr = malloc (rows * sizeof(int*));
    int *sizeArr = malloc(rows * sizeof(int));

    int r = 0, c;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePtr) != NULL){
        sizeArr[r] = cols = atoi(strtok(line, ";"));
        jaggedArr[r] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
            jaggedArr[r][c] = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        }
        SortLists(jaggedArr[r++], cols);
    }
    fclose(filePtr);
    //check print and deallocation
    for(r = 0;r < rows; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < sizeArr[r]; ++c)
            printf("%d ", jaggedArr[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
        free(jaggedArr[r]);
    }
    free(jaggedArr);
    free(sizeArr);
    return 0;
}

void SortLists(int list[], int size){
    int i,j,temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i){
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j){
            if (list[i] > list[j]){
                temp =  list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. May i ask, is the line `fscanf(filePtr, "%d ", &rows);` get the rows number of the text as it is the first  number in the text file ? Also, what is the pointer `*sizeArr` do ? I try to run your code with the text file but its not working so there must be something missing here.

Comment: @user4075830 _it is the first number in the text file_ yes.  _what is the pointer *sizeArr do ?_ You need to keep the size because the size is different for each row.

Comment: thank you for answer. What if I want to sort for the elements in the array first ? I try `SortLists(jaggedArr[sizeArr [i]],rows);` but it not working.

Comment: @user4075830 `for(i=0;i<rows;++i)SortLists(jaggedArr[i], sizeArr[i]);` When dividing the sort process. After the input can not be in front of the input element. (after while-loop)

Comment: What do you mean by dividing the sort process ?I'm very sorry for asking so many nooby questions

Comment: @user4075830 _What if I want to sort for the elements in the array first ?_ The Maybe  I also do not know the meaning of this. SortLists can not be used to it as long as such that that replacing a row in the first element if.

Comment: If I have an input file such that the rows are not in ascending order, I want to use the sort method to sort these rows so that the output will be in ascending order. Sorry for the confusing. For example, my input file is 
`2
6; 4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 2
3; 2, 5, 7`
the my output is 
`2 5 7 
2 4 5 7 8 9`

Comment: @user4075830 In other words, how is that you sort the rows by the number of elements in the row?

Comment: yes, that what i'm wondering about. i think that if i stored the rows number in an array, maybe i can use SortList to sort that array ?

Comment: @user4075830 It is not possible by `SortLists` because it is what you want to sort an array with the specified number of elements. You need to write another function. E.g `void SortRows(int *jaggedArr[], int size, int *rowSize);`. call SortRows(jaggedArr, rows, sizeArr);

Answer (score 0):

for extra question.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void SortLists(int list[], int size);
void SortRows(int *jaggedArr[], int size, int *rowSize);

int main(void){
    int row1[] = {4,7,8,9,5,2};
    int row2[] = {2,5,7};
    int *jaggedArr[] = { row1, row2};
    int rows = 2;
    int sizeArr[] = {6,3};
    int i, r, c;
    for(i=0;i<rows;++i)
        SortLists(jaggedArr[i], sizeArr[i]);
    for(r = 0;r < rows; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < sizeArr[r]; ++c)
            printf("%d ", jaggedArr[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    SortRows(jaggedArr, rows, sizeArr);
    for(r = 0;r < rows; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < sizeArr[r]; ++c)
            printf("%d ", jaggedArr[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void SortLists(int list[], int size){
    int i,j,temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i){
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j){
            if (list[i] > list[j]){
                temp =  list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void SortRows(int *jaggedArr[], int size, int *rowSize){
    int i,j,temp,*tempp;

    for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i){
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j){
            if (rowSize[i] > rowSize[j]){
                //swap in pairs
                temp =  rowSize[i];
                rowSize[i] = rowSize[j];
                rowSize[j] = temp;
                tempp =  jaggedArr[i];
                jaggedArr[i] = jaggedArr[j];
                jaggedArr[j] = tempp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void SortLists(int list[], int size);
void SortRows(int *jaggedArr[], int size);

int main(void){
    int row1[] = {6, 4,7,8,9,5,2};//The first element represents the number of elements.
    int row2[] = {3, 2,5,7};
    int *jaggedArr[] = { row1, row2};
    int rows = 2;
    //int sizeArr[] = {6,3};//Not required
    int i, r, c;
    for(i=0;i<rows;++i)
        SortLists(jaggedArr[i]+1, jaggedArr[i][0]);

    SortRows(jaggedArr, rows);
    for(r = 0;r < rows; ++r){
        for(c = 1; c <= jaggedArr[r][0]; ++c)
            printf("%d ", jaggedArr[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void SortLists(int list[], int size){
    int i,j,temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i){
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j){
            if (list[i] > list[j]){
                temp =  list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void SortRows(int *jaggedArr[], int size){
    int i,j,*tempp;

    for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i){
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j){
            if (jaggedArr[i][0] > jaggedArr[j][0]){
                tempp =  jaggedArr[i];
                jaggedArr[i] = jaggedArr[j];
                jaggedArr[j] = tempp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```